# core.symlinks entry outputted twice in git config list?

Tags: git, git-config

I found in my config list* the following entry doubled :

```
git config -l | sort
... (irrelevant here)
core.symlinks=false
core.symlinks=false
... (irrelevant here)
```

After a short pondering, I thought I had figured out why : Hey, of course! I didn't specify the source for the config list, therefore the output I see is the concatenation of entries from all sources... (I remember having observed that result before, for entries I had set both at local and global levels) so (after [a short visit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_description) [in the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coresymlinks)) I checked separately :

```
git config -l --local | sort
... (irrelevant here)
core.symlinks=false
... (irrelevant here)

git config -l --global | sort
(no line about core.symlinks at all)
```

Odd. One in `local` and none in `global`. Maybe `system`?

```
git config -l --system | sort
(no line about core.symlinks at all)
```

And at this point I can't support my first guess any more... so where is the "other" entry coming from, if not from `global` or `system` ? Is it just something about the way git builds the config list output that I'm missing and is causing this odd result?

---

* (while searching for something totally unrelated. So I'm the first to admit this question isn't crucial to the completion of any task, I just wanted to find out what's the reason behind what I observed, if anyone knows off the top of their head)

Comment: which the S.O.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see all the git settings that you currently have (both at the user and generic level) run:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

> *Note* 
>   Remember that if it is located in a directory that contains a git project, you will also get the configuration of it.

---

#### git config levels and files <sup>[1](https://es.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-config)</sup>

Before we further discuss `git config` usage, let's take a moment to cover configuration levels. The `git config` command can accept arguments to specify which configuration level to operate on. The following configuration levels are available:

- **--local**
   By default, `git config` will write to a local level if no configuration option is passed. Local level configuration is applied to the context repository `git config` gets invoked in. Local configuration values are stored in a file that can be found in the repo's .git directory: `.git/config`
- **--global**
  Global level configuration is user-specific, meaning it is applied to an operating system user. Global configuration values are stored in a file that is located in a user's home directory. `~ /.gitconfig` on unix systems and `C:\Users\<username>\.gitconfig` on windows
- **--system**
  System-level configuration is applied across an entire machine. This covers all users on an operating system and all repos. The system level configuration file lives in a `gitconfig` file off the system root path. `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig` on unix systems. On windows this file can be found at `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Git\config` on Windows XP, and in `C:\ProgramData\Git\config` on Windows Vista and newer.

Thus the order of priority for configuration levels is: local, global, system. This means when looking for a configuration value, Git will start at the local level and bubble up to the system level.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I see the double entry now. Strangely, it's both in `C:\\ProgramData/Git/config` and in the local .git of the specific repo but `--system` doesn't output the first, which seems unexpected.

Comment: I have added git config levels and files have if it helps @RomainValeri